# Is there a way to set `pull.rebase = true` only for one specific branch?

Tags: git

Normally, I have `pull.rebase = false` set globally. However, I am working on a project where I specifically want to enable `pull.rebase = true` only for the `main` branch. I know that I can manually write `git pull --rebase`, but I don't want to forget to do it.

I also don't want to set `pull.rebase = true` for the entire repo, because I don't always (or even usually) want to do a rebase pull.

Is there some way to set this on a per-*branch* basis?

Comment: Try `branch.main.rebase = true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a per branch configuration parameter [`branch.<name>.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtrebase) :

```
git config branch.my/branch.rebase true
```

Comment: Not relevant in OP's case, but for completion see also the related [`branch.autosetupRebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupRebase) config entry.

Comment: Not sure how I completely forgot this, but my wrong comment on the question is deleted now :-)